# Unity Addressables, make content update skippable

Tags: unity-game-engine, caching, assetbundle

For my application I have a couple of really large bundles and I want the user to be able to skip (specific) updates to the content.

At the moment I'm using the `Addressables.CheckForCatalogUpdates()` which lets me know If there's an update.

But using this function already lets my application know there's a new version of the assets and as soon as I load the asset it wants to use the new (still to download) version.

Ideally would like to end up with a flow similar to:

- Application checks for updates
- User gets prompted if he/she updates

  - => User updates

    - New content is downloaded
  - => User skips updates

    - content is loaded from cache
- Application continues

Help is much appreciated!
Regards,
Gijs